# Syntax of certutil.exe?

Tags: windows, certificate

On Windows, you can use certutil.exe to manage certificates. But it really has *lots* of options, and the command help (as much as Google) doesn't help clearly understanding it.

What is the exact meaning of these commands, all of which should be able to import a certificate into the local machine store?

```
certutil -addstore my <filename>
certutil -installcert <filename>
certutil -importcert <filename>
certutil -importpfx <filename>
```

I can guess the last one is for importing certificates from .pfx files; but shouldn't (some of) the other ones be able to do the same, too? And, what are the differences between the first three ones?

Answer (score 4):

Try commands with -?. You can get detailed informations about commands:

For example:

```
C:\>certutil -addstore -?

Usage:
  CertUtil [Options] -addstore CertificateStoreName InFile
  Add certificate to store
    CertificateStoreName -- Certificate store name.  See -store.
    InFile -- Certificate or CRL file to add to store.

Options:
  -f                -- Force overwrite
  -enterprise       -- Use local machine Enterprise registry certificate store
  -user             -- Use HKEY_CURRENT_USER keys or certificate store
  -GroupPolicy      -- Use Group Policy certificate store
  -gmt              -- Display times as GMT
  -seconds          -- Display times with seconds and milliseconds
  -v                -- Verbose operation
  -privatekey       -- Display password and private key data
  -dc DCName                -- Target a specific Domain Controller

CertUtil -?              -- Display a verb list (command list)
CertUtil -addstore -?    -- Display help text for the "addstore" verb
CertUtil -v -?           -- Display all help text for all verbs
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to distinguish is the difference between a certificate store and a certificate database.

From [MSDN - Public Key Infrastructure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb427432(v=VS.85).aspx)

> Certificate Database
>
> Saves certificate requests and issued and revoked certificates and certificate requests on the CA or RA.
>
> Certificate Store
>
> Saves issued certificates and pending or rejected certificate requests on the local computer.

This means `-addstore` is used when you want to add a certificate to the local store.

Next is the difference between `-installcert` and `-importcert`. The key is to distinguish the difference between an install and an import.

The file used for `-importcert` must be a single certificate.

The file used for `-installcert` can be a certificate chain (PKCS #7 or X.509 v3) or a single certificate.

Finally this means `-installpfx` will install a single PFX (PKCS #12) certificate or a certificate chain.

Comment: I still see lots of overlapping between them... can you please clarify it a bit?